# CLLocationManager didDetermineState method not called when app is in Background

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager, cllocation, geofencing, clregion

I am using **Geofencing** for one of my application. But I got one issue in it. My application is not called **- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region** when application is in **Background** mode.

I check for **Background app refresh** flag is **ON** in settings.

Below is my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
    if (state == CLRegionStateInside)
    {
            NSLog(@"is in target region");
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.alertBody =  @"You are IN of REGION";
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
            NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notification.timeZone = timezone;
            notification.alertAction = @"Show";
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
    else
    {
           NSLog(@"is out of target region");
           UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.alertBody = @"You are OUT of REGION";
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
            NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notification.timeZone = timezone;
            notification.alertAction = @"Show";
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
  }
}
```

**CLLocationManager** is set properly. I reseach on it, but didn't get proper soluction for my proble. Can anyone help me in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. It's because I have marked Location Update in backgournd. [image: Here is image.]